# Duvida com xhr.response

Tags: javascript, json

Possuo o seguinte código JavaScript:

```
function load(){
    var validationEmail = Email.value;
    var validaationCode = Code.value;

    var json = JSON.stringify({"userName": validationEmail, "codeCustomer": validaationCode});
    var url = "http://minha url";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
             console.log(xhr.response);

             if(xhr.response.value != false){

                console.log("kkkkkkk");
                document.getElementById("rootSingUp").innerHTML = loadSingUpPG1();
             }
        }
    }

    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

Esse código está gerando um JSON e enviando para meu webservide e com o xhr.response estou pegando o retorno dessa requisição.

No primeiro IF, quando dou **console.log(xhr.response)** ele me retorna **true** ou **false** corretamente.

porém quando tento executar o segundo if ele nem entra nessa segunda condição

Comment: tem como você mostrar uma imagem do resultado do **console.log(xhr.response);** ?

Comment: Aconselho a utilizar uma biblioteca que facilite sua vida tipo o axios.
Caso não você pode olhar a aba de desenvolvedor do chrome e ver o resultado. value somente estará disponível se voce retornar um contentType apropriado.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response